# Finding an acute angle $K$ such that $\csc 4+\csc8+\csc16+\csc32+\dots+\csc8192=2\csc K$

Tags: trigonometry

I got this question in my class a bit ago and its solution wasn't discussed. So-

> If
> $$\csc 4+\csc8+\csc16+\csc32+\dots+\csc8192=2\csc K $$
> where $K$ is an acute angle, find $K$

(Note that the cosec terms include powers of $2$ from $2^2$ to $2^{13}$)

I am unsure what the answer is and would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the trick here is to use the identity $\cot (x)+\csc (x)=\cot (\frac{x}{2})$ so I'll start off by showing that $\cot (x)+\csc (x)=\cot (\frac{x}{2})$. By simply writing the terms out we have $$\cot (x) + \csc (x)=\frac{\cos (x)}{\sin (x)}+\frac{1}{\sin (x)}=\frac{\cos(x)+1}{\sin (x)}=\frac{2\cos^2(\frac{x}{2})-1+1}{2\sin(\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{x}{2})}=\cot(\frac{x}{2})$$

So then for your equation we have

\begin{align}
\csc(4)+\csc(8)+\cdots+\csc(8192)&=2\csc(K) \\
\csc(4)+\csc(8)+\cdots+\csc(8192)+\cot(8192)&=2\csc(K)+\cot(8192) \\
\end{align}

From here we can apply the identity above so

\begin{align}
\csc(4)+\csc(8)+\cdots+\csc(4096)+\csc(8192)+\cot(8192)&=2\csc(K)+\cot(8192) \\
\csc(4)+\csc(8)+\cdots+\csc(4096)+\cot(4096)&=2\csc(K)+\cot(8192) \\
&\;\,\vdots \\
\cot(4)&=2\csc(K)+\cot(8192)
\end{align}
Which simplifies the equation a lot.

$$\cot(4)=2\csc(K)+\cot(8192)\Rightarrow \csc(K)=\frac{\cot(4)-\cot(8192)}{2}$$

I think the rest should be doable.

Comment: We should not encourage such no-effort questions by answering them.

Comment: I am sorry if my question was not presented properly and i deliberately didnt include my method because it wasnt efficient. What does a no-effort question means though?